What happens to an electron inside an uniform, time-varying magnetic field?
Suppose I have a really long coil with a current running through it, such that there's a pretty uniform magnetic field along the center axis. Now suppose I place a tiny charged particle, like an electron, at the center axis. What happens to the particle as I increase the current in the coil, thus increasing the magnetic field?

A force is exerted on the electron, given by $F = qv \times B$.

Assuming the electron is initially at rest, the following will happen.
As the magnetic field is varying, an electric field will be induced, conforming to the Faraday-Maxwell equation:
$$\nabla\times\vec{E}=\frac{\partial\vec{B}}{\partial t}$$
This electric field will cause the initially at rest electron to accelerate. Once the electron is moving, the magnetic field will also begin to act on the electron as well.
The force on the electron is given by the Lorentz force Law
$$\vec{F}=q(\vec{E} + (\vec{v}\times\vec{B}))$$
